# jQuery fadeIn() not giving the result I want

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, icons

[Site Link](http://find.netai.net)
If you scroll down a little you're gonna see some social icons and when hovered they show a simple tooltip that I made in jQuery using `fadeIn()` on `hover()` event. So the problem is I want something like in this [this](http://demo.joomla-monster.com/216-jm-joomclassifieds#jm-bottom3) page (scroll down a little to see the icons). How can I accomplish such effect using fadeIn or any other jQuery effect?

**HTML for one icon:**

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 tooltip-toggler">
    <a href="#">
        <div id="facebookIcon" class="social-round">
            <span class="fa fa-facebook"></span>
        </div>
    </a>
    <span class="social-tooltip fb">Facebook</span>
</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
$(".tooltip-toggler").hover(function(e) {
    $(this).children(".social-tooltip").fadeIn(100);
}, function(e) {
    $(this).children(".social-tooltip").fadeOut(100);
});
```

**Related CSS:**

```
.tooltip-toggler {
    position: relative;
}   
.social-tooltip {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -45px;
    left: -20px;
    width: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    -moz-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    -o-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: 0.3s ease-out;
}
```

[jSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/cUf2x/) ( Please expand the result window wide to see the proper result )

Comment: will u able to add me the fiddle for this.

Comment: You have to animate the position too, so fadeIn won't be enough. You should do: Hover, then animate opacity(which is what fadeIn does) and the position.

Comment: add ur css style to this

Comment: You can also acheive it by css by postioning and animating on hover

Comment: @Benjamin added some css

Comment: Please wait I am creating a fiddle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `animate`

```
$(".tooltip-toggler").hover(function(e) {
    $(".social-tooltip", this).animate({'top':'-45px', 'opacity':1},200)
}, function(e) {
   $(".social-tooltip", this).animate({'top':'-100px', 'opacity':0},200)
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/a5Tfu/6/)

**UPDATE**

Here's link to your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cUf2x/1/)

Comment: Thank you really very much but can you apply that on the given fiddle please?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to give just `fade-in` effect for icons, use the following class.

```
.social-round:hover
{
  opacity:0.7;
}
```

**NOTE:** I am not talking about the tool tip here. I am just giving answer based on your reference link.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/cUf2x/2/)

Comment: THank you very much but I didn't question that

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".social-round p").mouseenter(function(){
    var tooltip = $(this).parents(".tooltip-toggler").find(".social-tooltip");
      tooltip.animate({
        top: "+=30",
        opacity:"1",
    }, 0);
});
$(".social-round p").mouseleave(function() {
    var tooltip = $(this).parents(".tooltip-toggler").find(".social-tooltip");
      tooltip.animate({
        top: "-=30",
        opacity:"0",
    }, 100);
});
```

Try the above code this may help u to acheive your target and also check the demo
[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/2qJ8D/)

Make a thumbs up if this works for u

Answer (score 0):

make a http://www.jsfiddle.net/k8vAv/ 
pls ..

```
    also in your desired example ether are a lot of css and js involved.<br>
    you must animate from a position to other, on hover.
```

I give you few ex to choose :) 
http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/SLGdE/16/

I like more this this 
http://jsfiddle.net/4EAnU/16/

Answer (score -3):

`$(this).children(".social-tooltip").fadeIn(100);` -->   `$(this).find(".social-tooltip").fadeIn(100);`

same as the next one

Comment: OMG... where is your .social-tooltip class?